# Post as page on page MVC Facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Without much trouble I managed to post status messages on my personal Facebook feed. But what I'm trying to achieve is to post messages on a my page as the page.

```
 public class Facebook
        {
            private const string FacebookApiId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            private const string FacebookApiSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            string scope = "publish_stream,manage_pages";


            private const string AuthenticationUrlFormat = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages";


            static string GetAccesToken(string apiId, string apiSecret)
            {

                string url = string.Format(AuthenticationUrlFormat, apiId, apiSecret);
                string accesToken = string.Empty;
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(responseString);

                    accesToken = query["access_token"];
                }
                if (accesToken.Trim().Length == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("no Access Token");
                }

                return accesToken;

            }

            static void PostMessage(string accessToken, JobOfferModel message)
            {
                try
                {
                    FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

                    dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
                    messagePost.access_token = accessToken;

                    messagePost.name = message.JobTitle;
                    messagePost.message = message.Content;
                    messagePost.caption = "www.Site.com";





                    facebookClient.Post("me/feed", messagePost);
                }
                catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
```

Comment: where do you guys keep copying your code from? publish_stream is deprecated since YEARS...anyway, you need to use a page token. this question has been asked many times on stackoverflow, just search.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Im kinda new to this, so i'm using the top results of what google shows me :)

Comment: always take a look at the facebook docs first, they offer example code and all the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

As luschn mentioned, you need to use a page access token to post as a page. You can get this by making an API call to the 'me/accounts' endpoint. This will return a list of the pages you manage, and an access token for each.

Using a page's access token, make the next request to 'me/feed' to post as that page. You can get more details about using page access tokens here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

You should also update your login scope to use the new 'publish_actions' permission instead of 'publish_stream'.